# vi editor, how to replace third match on every line

Tags: regex, vi

Using the vi editor, I want to replace the third occurrence of ":" on each line to ":1:". What is the correct search and replace command?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```
%s/^\([^:]*:[^:]*:[^:*]\):\(.*\)/\1:1:\2/
```

where

`%` means all lines;

`s` is the substitution command;

`/\([^:]*:[^:]*:[^:*]\):\(.*\)/` matches three colon-delimited sequences of any number (including zero) of non-colons, starting at the beginning of the line, followed by a colon and the remainder of the line, capturing everything before and everything after the third colon; and

`/\1:1:\2/` (where the lead slash is also the trailing slash of the pattern) is the replacement string, with `\1` and `\2` representing the first and second captured groups, respectively, and `:1:` being literal text.